# how to add SSL in my application?

Tags: java, http, jsp, ssl, https

I just completed the chat application using **Java** which is working fine .

Now my Team Leader asked me to add the Secure Socket Layer(**SSL**) in the application.

**Without SSL :** I used this configuration in **server.xml**

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="200" port="8089" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

**To add SSL :** I have added the below code in my **server.xml**

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"  maxThreads="150" port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"  />
```

But I am getting the page as **Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage**

Can any one tell me how to add the feature ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First you must create a certificate:

   %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

   (You must choose a password then, "123456" in example)

   After you filled out all the informations you will get a .keystore in your home-directory (C:/Users/tim/.keystore).
2. Remove the Protocol and the sslProtocol from the connector!
3. Add

   ```
   keystoreFile="C:/Users/tim/.keystore"
   ```

   and

   ```
   keystorePass="123456"
   ```

   to the Connector.

Here we go. Start the server, open the browser and navigate to https:// localhost/

Comment: Btw, chrome will not allow you to open your self-signed cert. Try ie, firefox or opera instead. They will give you a "Error" that you cant trust yourself, trust your server anyway!

Comment: I have created that keystore and followed the steps you informed.Now when I run the URL **https://localhost:8084/CustomerChat_V1.00.01/** I am getting **certificate error** in **red color**.But my application runs

Comment: The "certificate error" means that no official organization has created this certificate! Try to force the load of the webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Its loaded but still shows some "certificate error". But my application works fine.

Comment: The "certificate error" means that no official organization has created this certificate! Try to force the load of the webpage.

Comment: How to get the **chain certificate** ?

Comment: There is no chain certificate, but there is a certificate chain. Why do you need the chains? there is only on chain-element, its the certificate you see in your browser. Only if you accept the certificatre you can see this chain-element installed in your computer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24040/discussion-between-peter-rader-and-anand)

Comment: Thanks for your support...Can U please come for chat ? I have some more doubts ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're refering to Tomcat see the [SSL Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) on how to setup SSL.
In order to enable SSL you need a certficate, you should go through the tutorial linked above and do it step by step.

> But I am getting the page as Internet Explorer cannot display the
>   webpage

Then you should check What the log file (catalina.out) says.

Comment: I have generated keystore.jks and how can I include it in my application ?

Comment: @Anand By setting the keystoreFile attribute of the Connector element in your server.xml . It's described in the secton "
Edit the Tomcat Configuration File"

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have created the **crt** file too. But , In that I don't know how can I import the certificate.I cant understand those things.Can you explain it in simple words.

Comment: How to download the **chain certificate** ?

Comment: @Anand If you've created a certificate by yourself then there is no chain. This applies only to certificate authorities. The browser would check whether a certificate is  trustworthy.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't generated the **crt** ,I have generated only **keystore.jks** and **csr** file only .These files are in my **java home**.